# Scala object initialization

Tags: scala

I have an object:

```
object A {
 val init = println("Hello")
}
```

I use it in a trait:

```
trait SomeTratit {
  val a = A.init
}
```

Then I use trait it in a class:

```
class SomeClass extends SomeTrait
```

When I instantiate SomeClass with `new SomeClass` I expect to see `"Hello"` in the console, but don't get it. Why?

Also I expect to see "Hello" only once while instantiating several objects, but don't see any "Hello" in console

Comment: Looks like a bug of Scala to me.

Comment: bug in Scala or in REPL? Tried this only in REPL

Comment: I can confirm it happens both inside and outside the REPL. It doesn't happen if you replace `println("Hello")` with `{ println("Hello"); 1 }`, so it looks like an optimization for `Unit` gone awry.

Comment: @maks Post it on [the issue tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: how I can get such behaviour, I mean performing some side effect only once when instantiating objects which mix in that trait without? I've tried to simply call `A.init` in the body of the trait, it works but compiler emits warning

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this should be considered a bug, but here's HOW this happened.

If you look at the generated bytecode of `object A`, it's like this:

```
public final class A$ {
  public static final A$ MODULE$;

  private final scala.runtime.BoxedUnit init;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class A$
       3: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public void init();
    Code:
       0: return

  private A$();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #16                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: putstatic     #18                 // Field MODULE$:LA$;
       8: aload_0
       9: getstatic     #23                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
      12: ldc           #25                 // String Hello
      14: invokevirtual #29                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      17: getstatic     #34                 // Field scala/runtime/BoxedUnit.UNIT:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
      20: putfield      #36                 // Field init:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
      23: return
}
```

You can find the `println("Hello")` you expected in the constructor of `A$`, but there's nothing in `init()`. This is perfectly correct because it is you intention that `println("Hello")` would not be executed every time when you called `init()`, right?

However, the problem comes in `SomeClass`:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeTrait {
  public void a();
    Code:
       0: return

  public void SomeTrait$_setter_$a_$eq(scala.runtime.BoxedUnit);
    Code:
       0: return

  public SomeClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #21                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: invokestatic  #27                 // Method SomeTrait$class.$init$:(LSomeTrait;)V
       8: return
}
```

What?! There's nothing in `SomeClass.a()`, either! But think about it, it's also perfectly reasonable: why would I bother calling it since there's literally nothing in `A$.init()` and it returns nothing (i.e. no field to be set)? Why not just optimize that out (Maybe Java did this optimization. Or Scala did. I don't know)? However, this optimization also erase the only appearance of `A$`, which means no constructor will be called for `A$`. That's why the `Hello` never appeared.

However, if you change the code a little bit so that the bytecode of `init()` will not be empty, like this:

```
object A {
  val init = { println("Hello"); 1 }
}
```

which compiles to the following bytecode:

```
public int init();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #17                 // Field init:I
     4: ireturn
```

in which case you will find the bytecode for `SomeClass.a()` like this:

```
public int a();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #15                 // Field a:I
     4: ireturn
```

where the field was set in `SomeTrait$class`:

```
public abstract class SomeTrait$class {
  public static void $init$(SomeTrait);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getstatic     #13                 // Field A$.MODULE$:LA$;
       4: invokevirtual #17                 // Method A$.init:()I
       7: invokeinterface #23,  2           // InterfaceMethod SomeTrait.SomeTrait$_setter_$a_$eq:(I)V
       12: return
}
```

`A$.init()` is called to set this field, so in this case you can expect `Hello` to appear.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need such side-effect in your code - you can see "hello" when accessing A directly (so just mention A in your trait). This is a feature of objects - they don't initialize while they don't really need to:

```
scala> object A {val a = println("hello"); val b = (); println("bye") }
defined module A

scala> A.b

scala> A.a

scala> A
hello
bye
res10: A.type = A$@1be2f5d8
```

You may notice simmilar behavior for type members:

```
scala> object A {println("init"); type T = Int }
defined module A

scala> val i: A.T = 5
i: A.T = 5

scala> A
init
res15: A.type = A$@73f5477e

scala>
```

Comment: This seems like complete madness.

Comment: @AndyHayden I think putting a block of side-effectful code returning Unit inside an immutable 'val' (aka constant) is a madness :) I don't know why compiler even allows that (instead of just forcing everyone to use regular inialization sections). Really, in 5 years I never needed something like this. If I really needed such delayed initialization (it wouldn't be for useless Unit though) - I'd use 'lazy val'

Comment: most painful thing in scala is its regular initialization, like guess what this code would print: object A{val a = b; val b= 5; println(a)}; A

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like it's related with the compiler optimization. For example, the code as given doesn't show the `"Hello"` message, because the compiler seems to infer that as `A.init` is of type `Unit`, the local `val a` of `SomeTrait` will always end up with the same constant value. So the compiler just assign it and that's it.

Nonetheless, if you make the evaluation of `init` not eager, by making the field `init` at `Object A` also `lazy`, then the message is actually printed:

```
object A {
  lazy val init = println("Hello")
}
```

Moreover, even if you just do the same but force the `init` function in `Object A` to return some meaningful value, then the message will also be printed, since the compiler cannot infer the resulting value to be constant.

```
  object A {
    val init = { println("Hello"); 1} // returns some integer
  }

  trait SomeTrait {
    val a = A.init
  }

  class SomeClass extends SomeTrait
```

This is my interpretation, but I can be missing something. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a in the trait all you did is copy a reference to function A.init into SomeTrait.a. You could then do a() to invoke the function and see the expected output.

Answer (score -4):

init is the type Unit, therefore assess the function is in vain.