# case object gets initialized to null - how is that even possible?

Tags: scala

I'm experiencing a bizarre bug. One of the case objects (only one) gets `null` as its value and obviously causes Null pointer exceptions later in the life. But: why?

I've tried different things (renaming objects, changing hesitance, even rewriting the same line twice, getting one of them to compile nice, while another gives `null`). I've cloned the repo to make sure it's not some funny transitive effect. Both Scala 2.11.4 and 2.11.5 cause the same.

The code is rather twisty and cutting it off its context makes little sense. But here it is, in case it rings any bells on someone else.

```
sealed trait A {}

sealed trait B extends A {}

sealed trait C { val n: Int }
object C {
  val C1: C = new C { val n = 1 }
  val C2: C = new C { val n = 2 }
  val C3: C = new C { val n = 3 }
  val C4a: C = new C { val n = 4 }
  val C4b: C = new C { val n = 5 }
}

class D (depends: Seq[C], f: (Seq[Double]) => Double) {
  // ...methods removed
}

sealed trait E { val e: Int = 1 }

object D {
  import C._

  private def f( v: Seq[Double] ): Double = 0

  private def list( acc: Boolean ) = List(
    C1, C2, C3,
    if (acc) C4a else C4b
  )

  case object D1 extends D( list(true), f ) with E   // <-- this gets to be 'null'!!
  case object D2 extends D( list(false), f )

  val keys: Seq[D] = List(D1, D2)

  println(s"D1: $D1")
  println(s"D2: $D2")

  assert(D1 != null)    // <-- caught here
  assert(D2 != null)
}
```

I tried to keep as much of the details in the code, as possible, in case they matter somehow.

What can this be?

I tagged it as 'heisenbug' but when I compile stuff, it's consistent (i.e. successive test runs would always produce the same effect).

EDIT: I originally said this only happened with `sbt test` (and not `sbt run`) but that's not true. Both were equally affected.

EDIT: Seems [@dk14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1809978/dk14) has filed this as [Scala issue 9115](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9115). Thanks!

Comment: This code can't be executed. Can you create an executable example that produces the unexpected behavior?

Comment: I tried that, but the reduced sample worked as intended (i.e. no null). The bigger project that has the problem is proprietary, so I cannot reveal more than this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea what exactly happens, but I suspect there is some kind of construction order involved. I can reproduce the problem 100% of the time, if I paste the code and do

```
scala> D.D1
D1: null
D2: D2
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:151)
  ... 47 elided
```

Also if I ask for `D2` first, it will fail too, so it's not related to `E`.

```
scala> D.D2
D1: D1
D2: null
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
  at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:151)
  ... 47 elided
```

But if I ask for `D` first, it works 100% of the time:

```
scala> D
D1: D1
D2: D2
res1: D.type = D$@50434135

scala> D.D1
res2: D.D1.type = D1
```

---

I succeed to distill the problem into shorter code example:

```
class Bug(val f: Int) {}

object Bug {
  private def f(n: Int): Int = n

  case object Bug1 extends Bug(f(1))
  case object Bug2 extends Bug(f(2))

  val values: List[Bug] = List(Bug1, Bug2)

  println(s"1: $Bug1")
  println(s"2: $Bug2")
}
```

Asking for `Bug.Bug1` will fail. Yet if I remove `println` lines - everything works. Or "execute" `Bug` first. Yet  having `values` is ok.

I guess some initialisation locks go wrong way, when asking directly for `Bug.Bug1` or `Bug.Bug2`.

Comment: Awesome work! In my original sample, I solved the issue by making 'keys' 'lazy val', and removing the tests within the parent object. Seems an object within an object might be null transitionally, and one must beware not to anchor that by storing the value too early. Thanks!!

Comment: Marked yours as the official answer since it helped me solve the problem at my end! **bows**

Answer (score 1):

It's not working only when you directly access `D.D1` or `D.D2` before `D` object itself as it's not initialized here, so `case object` values are still `null`'s. Seems like a bug for me (should initialize `D` before calling `D.D1`). Workaround: just call `D` itself (to run initialization) somewhere before `D.D1`. See, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26072435/1809978 - lazy initialization is actually a feature, but not in the case you've found. Simplified example:

```
object D {
  def aaa = 1 //that’s the reason
  class Z (depends: Any)
  case object D1 extends Z(aaa) // <-- this gets to be 'null'!!
  case object D2 extends Z(aaa)
  println(D1) 
  println(D2) 
}
```

Results :

```
defined object D
scala> D.D1
null
D2
res32: D.D1.type = D1
```

After re-definition of `D`:

```
defined object D
scala> D.D2
D1
null
res34: D.D2.type = D2
```

So scala forgots to initialize the requested sub-object (if it refers to some another member of object inside sub-object's definition) before running enclosing object initialization. It initializes this sub-object after (when aaa is defined). I think primary intention was to initialize all referred members before requested member, but it's still seems a bug as it changes intialization order, depending on how D was used in the code.

Comment: So do you see this as a bug of Scala? I was expecting the enclosed objects to get initialized first, but it seems they shouldn't be accessed from within the outer object's constructor (unless the access is lazy, that is).

Comment: in this case it's bug of scala's object's lazy initialization - see my update